# LISP - Breadth First Search

Tags: graph, lisp, breadth-first-search

I have an implementation of BFS I got elsewhere and modified slightly, but I am having problems with its input.
It takes a graph, and will take it as '((a b c) (b c) (c d))
But my input I am giving it is a weighted graph... I know it's not useful for the BFS, but I use the weights farther down the line later.   This input looks like
`'(

(a (b 3) (c 1))

(b (a 3) (d 1))

(c (a 1) (d2) (e 2))

)`
And so on.

My code:

```
(defun shortest-path (start end net)  
      (BFS end (list (list start)) net))

(defun BFS (end queue net)  
  (if (null queue)  
      nil  
      (expand-queue end (car queue) (cdr queue) net)))

(defun expand-queue (end path queue net)  
  (let ((node (car path)))  
        (if (eql node end)  
        (reverse path)  
        (BFS end
             (append queue  
                     (new-paths path node net))  
             net))))

(defun new-paths (path node net)  
  (mapcar #'(lambda (n)  
              (cons n path))  
          (cdr (assoc node net))))
```

I'm just not sure where I need to most likely modify it to accept the new style list, or make a help function to format it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify what the list that represents your graph means. Currently you have only given an example list.

When the graph has a syntax like:

```
graph = (node*)

node = (name nextnodename*)

name = SYMBOL

nextnodename = SYMBOL
```

Then a transformation function might be:

```
(defun convert-graph (graph)
  (mapcar (lambda (node)
            (destructuring-bind (name . nodes) node
              (cons name (mapcar #'first nodes))))
          graph))
```

or if you might need other extraction functions:

```
(defun convert-graph (graph &key (key #'first))
  (mapcar (lambda (node)
            (destructuring-bind (name . nodes) node
              (cons name (mapcar key nodes))))
          graph))
```

Example:

```
(convert-graph '((a (b 3) (c 1))
                 (b (a 3) (d 1))
                 (c (a 1) (d 2) (e 2)))
               :key #'first)

((A B C) (B A D) (C A D E))
```

Now you might need to remove duplicate links. But this depends on the syntax and semantics of your graph description.

Comment: This works perfect.   This is a bit beyond my Lisp skills so thank you very much for helping with it.